# TypeError in cudf.pandas

Tags: python, pandas, clickhouse, rapids, cudf

I am using the Rapids library for Pandas. On top of my code:

```
import cudf.pandas

cudf.pandas.install()
import pandas as pd
```

I'm using https://clickhouse-driver.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ and `client.insert_dataframe` method. When I'm trying to insert data, faced with the error:

```
TypeError: Unsupported column type: <class 'cudf.pandas._wrappers.numpy.ndarray'>. list or tuple is expected.
```

I don't know why is happening, checked datetypes of columns they are floats and datetimes.

Please tell me how to convert a dataframe to a view that can be inserted with clickhouse-client

Comment: Why didn't you provide more code to make it easier to answer the question? By the way, doesn't this solve the problem: https://docs.rapids.ai/api/cudf/legacy/api_docs/api/cudf.dataframe.to_pandas/ ?

Answer (score 1):

(I'm a maintainer for cuDF)

The issue is with `cudf.pandas`, and it is that when `cudf.pandas` is enabled, `Series.values` returns a proxy type rather than a true numpy `ndarray`:

```py
import cudf.pandas
cudf.pandas.install()

import pandas as pd

print(type(pd.Series([1, 2, 3]).values))
cudf.pandas._wrappers.numpy.ndarray
```

My guess is that *somewhere* in the `clickhouse-driver` codebase, there's an `instancecheck` for `np.ndarray`.

We're thinking of solutions. Ideally though, more projects would avoid doing a hard `instancecheck()` for `np.ndarray`, and instead allow array-*like* objects using something like:

```py
arr = np.asarray(obj)
```

I've opened an issue against cudf where you can track progress: https://github.com/rapidsai/cudf/issues/14537

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs, the proper way to use `cudf.pandas` on your code is to:

> Just `%load_ext cudf.pandas` in Jupyter, or pass `-m cudf.pandas` on the command line.

Please see https://docs.rapids.ai/api/cudf/stable/cudf_pandas/usage for more detailed usage examples.